# Aplicação com JBOSS Wildfly responder através de DNS

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

eu sou extremamente iniciante nessa parte de configuração de ambiente e preciso colocar uma aplicação que desenvolvi em produção. Eu já tenho um domínio cadastrado e gostaria que o usuário, ao invés de digitar IP:8080/nomeApp, pudesse digitar o domínio da aplicação. Acontece que eu não faço ideia de como fazer isso no Jboss, já fiz anteriormente no IIS e a configuração costuma ser bem simples. Rodei a internet atrás disso, mas sem sucesso. Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde configuro isso?

Estou usando o Jboss Wildfly 10, a aplicação é em Java com Spring e estou subindo o servidor em modo standalone.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa da configuração do *jboss* na pasta `WEB-INF` do seu projeto. Para o Wildfly reconhecer o caminho (que não seja o default), adicione a seguinte tag `<context-root>` seguido do prefixo que deseja que fique na frente da sua aplicação, como você quer que ele seja executado na *raiz* basta adicionar a `/`

**WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
   <context-root>/</context-root>

  <!-- outras configs do projeto -->
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Além do sugerido pelo Paulo H. Hartmann, também alterei o meu standalone.xml para o seguinte:

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost, myAppDomain.com" default-web-module="myApp.war">
    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
</host>
```

Com essa configuração, consigo acessar minha aplicação também pelo DNS.